# Использование строки для доступа к полю

Tags: java, android

Как обратиться к полю другого класса Test.characterAnimation с помощью строки?

Comment: Наверное вам рефлексия нужна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием рефлексии:

```
String fieldName = "characterAnimation";
try
{
    Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    Test test = new Test();
    Object value = field.get(test);
    System.out.println(value);
}
catch (Exception ignored) { }
```

Если поле является статическим, то вместо `test` можно передавать `null`.

Если поле не является доступным в классе, в котором используется данный код, то может помочь:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```